# 'Latin (Helvetica)' Format in Word 2016 (High Sierra)

Tags: ms-office, formatting

Word 2016 for Mac is styling text as 'Normal + (Latin) Helvetica' when I paste it into a new document. I cannot remove the '(Latin) Helvetica' style by reapplying 'Normal' or directly formatting the text. How can I remove all instances of '(Latin) Helvetica' and substitute 'Normal'?

*Below: 'Normal + (Latin) Helvetica' on the left; 'Normal' on the right.*
[image: Example]

Comment: You may want to check the Word forums, I think there are discussions about these font issues there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved problem by updating the version of Word. I've updated to 15.39; and the problem has solved.